# How can react lazyload child route using react-router?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, lazy-loading

Now I am using `react-route` to control my routes!

You know I tried to build a single page app. There is only one entry file named 
`index.js`

When `index.js` is too heavy loading time will very long. Maybe 10000ms.

But there are many routes why must loaded them all first? If I can lazyload route not only child routes.

When I go to `admin` route it will load **js file of admin** and `about` will load **js file of about** , can I?

webpack bundle will have two files [name].js and come.js. But it too heavy.

Anyone meet the same problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do lazy loading of React Components with `react-router` in two ways.

**Webpack's `require.ensure` way**
When you go with this approach, you would be dealing with the react router object something like this,

```
childRoutes:[
    {
      path:"/pageone",
      getComponents:(a, cb) => require.ensure([], require => {cb(null, require("pages/PageOne"));})
    },
    {
      path:"/pagetwo",
      getComponents:(a, cb) => require.ensure([], require => {cb(null, require("pages/PageTwo"));})
    }
  ]
```

**Webpack's `bundle-loader` way**
When you go with this approach, you would be dealing with the webpack loaders option.

```
module: {
  loaders: [{
    test: /.*/,
    include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'pages/admin')],
    loader: 'bundle?lazy&name=admin'
   }]
}
```

You can find an [example](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/v0.13.3/examples/partial-app-loading) from `react-router` which uses `bundle-loader` and [here](https://medium.com/@Nadav.Dav/implementing-lazy-loading-with-webpack-and-react-router-f8497f895892#.jas6vj3um) is a nice blog about lazy-loading with bundle-loader and [here](https://medium.com/@puppybits/webpack-code-splitting-by-routes-92f96cf733f2#.5g34yhg2j) is a blog with `require.ensure`

Comment: I have tried to use this way 

**getComponent={(nextState, cb)=>{cb(null, require('./components/menu/MenuComboMain.react').default)}}** on Route element

Does this way have some advantages and disadvantages compare with yours

Comment: just `require` will bundle all the modules at one shot. `require.ensure` will create separate files to lazy load the modules